# PostgreSQL - Viewing Data from different tables based on a constraint on one of the tables

Tags: postgresql

Edited Post:

So I've got the following tables below, I am trying to display the fields name from UniMember, phone from table Staff and starting field from table Afl based on the constraint that the ending field in Afl is null. I'm very new Postgresql and have basically been stuck with this for 2 days. I have tried many different queries but haven't been able to get it to display.

The expected output should be along the lines of:

Name | Phone | Starting

Thanks!

```
create table UniMember (
    id          integer, -- PG: serial
    unswid      integer unique, -- staff/student id (can be null)
    password    ShortString not null,
    family      LongName,
    given       LongName not null,
    title       ShortName, -- e.g. "Prof", "A/Prof", "Dr", ...
    sortname    LongName not null,
    name        LongName not null,

    primary key (id)
);

create table Staff (
    id          integer references People(id),
    office      integer references Rooms(id),
    phone       PhoneNumber, -- full number, not just extension
    primary key (id) 
);

create table Afl (
    staff       integer references Staff(id),
    orgUnit     integer references OrgUnits(id),
    role        integer references Staff_roles(id),
    isPrimary   boolean, -- is this role the basis for their employment?
    starting    date not null, -- when they commenced this role
    ending      date,  -- when they finshed; null means current
    primary key (staff,orgUnit,role,starting)
);
```

Comment: You should post your table structure along with any attempted query you tried.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into INNER JOINS, ideally need to see all your tables but you need a common field between the tables (Primary and Secondary keys) to link the tables together and display the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view, which you can use to output your data the right way. You can do it as shown below.

```
create view test as select name, phone, starting 
from unimember a, staff b, afl c 
where b.id = c.staff
```

Now you can select on the view:

```
Select * from test;
```

A more clear definition on the output would be great next time you ask a question.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for this. I've tried this but the output is taking way too long to appear. Does it normally take quite a while?